# Is the freezing point of solution always lower?

Tags: solutions

If the freezing point of a solution always lower than that of the pure solvent or is it possible for it to end up being higher?

Comment: Depends on your definition of solution. Is $^2\ce{H2O}$ in $^1\ce{H2O}$ close enough? Because that's the only way I know to make a "solution" and have the FP go down.

Comment: Of course not. Whether you're talking only about aqueous solutions or other ones.

Comment: Thanks. There's no way the freezing point could not change either is there?

Comment: Whoops. Go up* sorry.

Comment: Consider the enthalpic and entropic contributions in the small solute limit. Entropy will win, lowering the freezing point.